# Three.js: How to prevent parts of mesh from shape dissapearing at larger distance

Tags: three.js, shapes

I have a geometry that should be visible from a close and large distance. It is a shape geometry. The material used is the basic mesh material. The code is like this:

```
        var shape = new THREE.Shape(geoPoints);
        var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x0000FF,
            wireframe: true
        });
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
```

When I use the wireframe property of the material, the geometry stays entirely visible. However, when I turn off the wireframe parts of the mesh dissapear from larger distance. This can be seen in the added figures:

Mesh basic material, wireframe off

[image]

Mesh basic material, wireframe on

[image]

How can this be solved? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting `obj.frustumCulled = false;` for things you draw. [Docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.frustumCulled)

Comment: Either `camera.far = bigNumber;`. [Docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.far)

Comment: @Docs Thanks for the tips, tried both but unfortunately they do not solve the problem

Comment: this requires a fiddle, it's impossible to debug from just the shots